# Erro ao consumir webservice NFSe com autenticação mútua - handshaking

Tags: c#, web-service, ssl, https, tls

Estou com um problema para consumir o webservice de Nota Fiscal Eletrônica da cidade de Sertãozinho. O servidor desta NFSe utiliza o Tomcat com autenticação mútua (handshaking). O endereço do servidor de produção é:

```
    [https://nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443/tbw/services/nfseSOAP?wsdl][1]
```

Na máquina de desenvolvimento eu instalei os certificados fornecidos pela Prefeitura, compostos pelas chaves raiz das autoridades certificadoras e a chave pública da prefeitura. Os arquivos fornecidos são:

- AC-Secretaria-da-Receita-Federal-do-Brasil-v3.cer
- ACVALID-RFB.cer
- Autoridade-Certificadora-Raiz-Brasileira-V2.cer
- Cert_pms-public.cer (PREFEITURA DE SERTÃOZINHO)

Todos estes certificados foram instalados tanto para o "CurrentUser" como "LocalMachine". Também fiz a tentativa de instalar os certificados nas pastas "Pessoal" e "Autoridades de Certificação Raiz Confiáveis".

Além destes certificados, também utilizo o certificado do cliente para assinar o XML da NFSE (arquivo pfx).

Estou utilizando o certificado do cliente para assinar o XML da nota e o certificado da prefeitura para criptografar a comunicação TLS. Abaixo listo o código que configura a comunicação, obtém o certificado e executa o consumo do método WS:

```
try
{
    // Tentativas de configurar a comunicação (códigos sugeridos por outros blogs)
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

    // A função ConfigurarWS apenas cria o EndPoint com o endereço de produção/homologação
    EndpointAddress endPoint = ConfigurarWS(ref myBinding);

    // instancia o proxy do webservice
    wsSertaozinhoProd.nfseClient nfseClient = new wsSertaozinhoProd.nfseClient(myBinding, endPoint);

    // atribui o certificado da prefeitura para o canal seguro
    // a função GetCertForWebService2 está abrindo o repositório de certificados em LocalMachine e Root (Autoridades de Certificação Raiz Confiáveis) e pesquisando o certificado por número de série
    nfseClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Security.GetCertForWebService2("2D279236B9F1B43B");  // MUNICIPIO

    // atribui as informações de cabeçalho e dados da nota fiscal
    wsSertaozinhoProd.input inputobj = new wsSertaozinhoProd.input();
    inputobj.nfseCabecMsg = GerarCabRecepcionarLoteRpsSincrono();
    inputobj.nfseDadosMsg = strXML;

    // executa o método de envio da nota e processa o retorno
    return LerXMLResposta(nfseClient.GerarNfse(inputobj).outputXML);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    csResult.bValidacao = false;
    csResult.strTipoRetorno = "ERROCOMUNICACAO";

    Util.LogEmArquivo.WriteLogEntry("Falha no envio da nota, método TramissaoWS() tentativa " + iTentativa + Environment.NewLine + " Exception: " + ex.Message, EventType.Error);
    Util.LogEmTela.AdicionaMsg("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
    Util.LogEmTela.AdicionaMsg("Tentando novamente, tentativa " + (iTentativa + 1) + " de " + QtdeTentativas);
    if (iTentativa == InternalConfig.Tentativas)
    {
        Util.LogEmTela.AdicionaMsg("Não foi possível enviar a nota fiscal, tentativas esgotadas");
        return csResult;
    }
}
```

O erro que está ocorrendo é:

- Error: Não foi possível estabelecer um canal seguro para SSL/TLS com autoridade 'nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443'.
- InnerException: A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.

Eu habilitei o trace para System.Net, System.Net.HttpListener, System.Net.Sockets e System.Net.Cache. Abaixo um trecho do log gerado pelo trace, aonde destaquei em negrito os pontos que estava focando para tentar resolver o problema. Uma mensagem que chama a atenção é quando informa que não foi possível encontrar o certificado.

Será que a configuração que estou realizando é suficiente para este formato mútuo de comunicação? Eu tentei informar o certificado do cliente para criar o canal de comunicação seguro, mas ocorreu outro erro, informando que o tipo de certificado não é compatível com o tipo de comunicação.

```
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] O tipo de instalação de SO atual é 'Client'.
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:12.4377543Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] WebRequest::Create(https://nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443/tbw/services/nfseSOAP)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.3489598Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] HttpWebRequest#13040701::HttpWebRequest(https://nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443/tbw/services/nfseSOAP#-1597284356)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.3489598Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] RAS com suporte: True
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.3645855Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting HttpWebRequest#13040701::HttpWebRequest() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.3802118Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting WebRequest::Create()   -> HttpWebRequest#13040701
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.3802118Z
  System.Net Error: 0 : [7532] Não é possível recuperar as configurações de proxy para o Uri 'https://nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443/tbw/services/nfseSOAP'. Código de erro: 12180.
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.4114633Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] ServicePoint#64906717::ServicePoint(nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.4114633Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Associating HttpWebRequest#13040701 with ServicePoint#64906717
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.4114633Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] HttpWebRequest#13040701::GetRequestStream()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.6936907Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Associating Connection#42644125 with HttpWebRequest#13040701
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7093164Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7249422Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Socket() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7249422Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#12507741::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7249422Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#12507741::Socket() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7340231Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] DNS::TryInternalResolve(nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7370249Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Connect(187.45.156.18:8443#312216896)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.7480326Z
  System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669 - Conexão criada de 192.168.2.18:13287 para 187.45.156.18:8443.
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8106960Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Connect() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8106960Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#12507741::Close()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8263223Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#12507741::Dispose()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8263223Z
  System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#12507741::Close() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8263223Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Connection#42644125 - Conexão criada de 192.168.2.18:13287 para 187.45.156.18:8443.
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8263223Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] TlsStream#43055348::.ctor(host=nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, #certs=1)
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8263223Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Associating HttpWebRequest#13040701 with ConnectStream#20438820
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8419469Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting HttpWebRequest#13040701::GetRequestStream()    -> ConnectStream#20438820
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8419469Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] ConnectStream#20438820::Write()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8419469Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from ConnectStream#20438820::Write
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:17.8419469Z

  ... DADOS DA NFE ...

  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting ConnectStream#20438820::Write() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0763383Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] ConnectStream#20438820::Close()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0763383Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting ConnectStream#20438820::Close() 
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0919635Z
  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7532] HttpWebRequest#13040701::GetResponse()
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0919635Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] HttpWebRequest#13040701 - Request: POST /tbw/services/nfseSOAP HTTP/1.1
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0919635Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] ConnectStream#20438820 - Enviando cabeçalhos
  {
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoyjb1qfQy7dOrMLMbyXyjYUAAAAAJpB1DKi1xkiXtyLcEon0joshTOqQUHtDtcASL4o4uDoACQAA
  SOAPAction: "http://nfse.abrasf.org.br/GerarNfse"
  Host: nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br:8443
  Content-Length: 12410
  Expect: 100-continue
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  }.
      ProcessId=12476
      DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.0919635Z
  System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253::.ctor(hostname=nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br,
#clientCertificates=1, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1075898Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Enumerando os pacotes de segurança:
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1119901Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     Negotiate
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1149924Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     NegoExtender
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1169943Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     Kerberos
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1199961Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     NTLM
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1219974Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     TSSSP
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1239988Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     pku2u
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1260002Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     WDigest
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1290019Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     Schannel
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1301347Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1301347Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     Default TLS SSP
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1301347Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532]     CREDSSP
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1301347Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Tentativa de reiniciar a sessão usando o certificado fornecido pelo usuário: [Version]
   V3

 [Subject]
   CN=MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128, OU=AR MAC BR, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, L=SERTAOZINHO, S=SP, C=BR
   Simple Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128
   Email Name: emerson.baldo@sertaozinho.sp.gov.br
   DNS Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128

 [Issuer]
   CN=AC VALID RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
   Simple Name: AC VALID RFB
   DNS Name: AC VALID RFB

 [Serial Number]
   2D279236B9F1B43B

 [Not Before]
   08/03/2018 18:09:59

 [Not After]
   08/03/2019 18:09:59

 [Thumbprint]
   640FA8E12C374BF9C4EAD743FB51FB1F8D2351B6

 [Signature Algorithm]
   sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

 [Public Key]
   Algorithm: RSA
   Length: 2048
   Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bd 68 20 34 8d 80 3a c1 31 75 32 9a 76 e4 8b 29 cb 80 8e fa bd 78 dc 39 96 e7 d9 a5 d3 08 89 0f 91 f7 c7 77 b0 1b 9b 8a 21 7f 86 e2 ae 0a 13 4f ee 1e 6d 16 08 7e ee b8 7c fd 77 3a ....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1457647Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Deixado com 1 certificados de cliente dos quais escolher.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1457647Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Tentando encontrar um certificado correspondente no repositório de certificados.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1457647Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Localizando a chave privada para o certificado: [Version]
   V3

 [Subject]
   CN=MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128, OU=AR MAC BR, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, L=SERTAOZINHO, S=SP, C=BR
   Simple Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128
   Email Name: emerson.baldo@sertaozinho.sp.gov.br
   DNS Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128

 [Issuer]
   CN=AC VALID RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
   Simple Name: AC VALID RFB
   DNS Name: AC VALID RFB

 [Serial Number]
   2D279236B9F1B43B

 [Not Before]
   08/03/2018 18:09:59

 [Not After]
   08/03/2019 18:09:59

 [Thumbprint]
   640FA8E12C374BF9C4EAD743FB51FB1F8D2351B6

 [Signature Algorithm]
   sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

 [Public Key]
   Algorithm: RSA
   Length: 2048
   Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bd 68 20 34 8d 80 3a c1 31 75 32 9a 76 e4 8b 29 cb 80 8e fa bd 78 dc 39 96 e7 d9 a5 d3 08 89 0f 91 f7 c7 77 b0 1b 9b 8a 21 7f 86 e2 ae 0a 13 4f ee 1e 6d 16 08 7e ee b8 7c fd 77 3a ....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1613889Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Não é possível encontrar o certificado no repositório LocalMachine ou CurrentUser.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1613889Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1770124Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1770124Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=139, retornou o código=ContinueNeeded).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1770124Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Send()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1770124Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Send
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.1770124Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Send()  -> Int32#139
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.2082655Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.2082655Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.2961358Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] 00000000 : 16 03 01 40 00                                  : ...@.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.3117593Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#5
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.3117593Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.3117593Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.3117593Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] (printing 1024 out of 2875)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.3117593Z

 .....

 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#2875
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.4680188Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.4680188Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.4836451Z

 ... DADOS NFE ...

 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#13509
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6399046Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = dbec100:7aa8d68, targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6399046Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, retornou o código=ContinueNeeded).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6399046Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6399046Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6399046Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] 00000000 : 16 03 01 40 00                                  : ...@.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6555309Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#5
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6555309Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6555309Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6555309Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] (printing 1024 out of 16384)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.6555309Z

 .....

 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#16384
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8241929Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = dbec100:7aa8d68, targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8261948Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, retornou o código=ContinueNeeded).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] 00000000 : 16 03 01 01 B7                                  : .....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#5
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8273951Z

 ......

 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#439
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.8898985Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = dbec100:7aa8d68, targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9055248Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, retornou o código=CredentialsNeeded).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9055248Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Há certificados fornecidos pelo usuário. O servidor especificou 181 emissor(es). Procurando certificados que correspondam a um dos emissores.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9211506Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Certificado selecionado: [Version]
   V3

 [Subject]
   CN=MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128, OU=AR MAC BR, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, L=SERTAOZINHO, S=SP, C=BR
   Simple Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128
   Email Name: emerson.baldo@sertaozinho.sp.gov.br
   DNS Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128

 [Issuer]
   CN=AC VALID RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
   Simple Name: AC VALID RFB
   DNS Name: AC VALID RFB

 [Serial Number]
   2D279236B9F1B43B

 [Not Before]
   08/03/2018 18:09:59

 [Not After]
   08/03/2019 18:09:59

 [Thumbprint]
   640FA8E12C374BF9C4EAD743FB51FB1F8D2351B6

 [Signature Algorithm]
   sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

 [Public Key]
   Algorithm: RSA
   Length: 2048
   Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bd 68 20 34 8d 80 3a c1 31 75 32 9a 76 e4 8b 29 cb 80 8e fa bd 78 dc 39 96 e7 d9 a5 d3 08 89 0f 91 f7 c7 77 b0 1b 9b 8a 21 7f 86 e2 ae 0a 13 4f ee 1e 6d 16 08 7e ee b8 7c fd 77 3a ....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9524031Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Deixado com 1 certificados de cliente dos quais escolher.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9524031Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Tentando encontrar um certificado correspondente no repositório de certificados.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9524031Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Localizando a chave privada para o certificado: [Version]
   V3

 [Subject]
   CN=MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128, OU=AR MAC BR, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, L=SERTAOZINHO, S=SP, C=BR
   Simple Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128
   Email Name: emerson.baldo@sertaozinho.sp.gov.br
   DNS Name: MUNICIPIO DE SERTAOZINHO:45371820000128

 [Issuer]
   CN=AC VALID RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
   Simple Name: AC VALID RFB
   DNS Name: AC VALID RFB

 [Serial Number]
   2D279236B9F1B43B

 [Not Before]
   08/03/2018 18:09:59

 [Not After]
   08/03/2019 18:09:59

 [Thumbprint]
   640FA8E12C374BF9C4EAD743FB51FB1F8D2351B6

 [Signature Algorithm]
   sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

 [Public Key]
   Algorithm: RSA
   Length: 2048
   Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bd 68 20 34 8d 80 3a c1 31 75 32 9a 76 e4 8b 29 cb 80 8e fa bd 78 dc 39 96 e7 d9 a5 d3 08 89 0f 91 f7 c7 77 b0 1b 9b 8a 21 7f 86 e2 ae 0a 13 4f ee 1e 6d 16 08 7e ee b8 7c fd 77 3a ....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9524031Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] SecureChannel#32685253 - Não é possível encontrar o certificado no repositório LocalMachine ou CurrentUser.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9524031Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] Usando o identificador de credencial armazenado em cache.
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9680283Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = dbec100:7aa8d68, targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9680283Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=141, retornou o código=ContinueNeeded).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9680283Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Send()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9680283Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Send
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:18.9680283Z

 .....

 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Send()  -> Int32#141
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0149071Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0149071Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0305350Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] 00000000 : 15 03 01 00 02                                  : .....
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0305350Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#5
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Receive()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Data from Socket#3578669::Receive
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] 00000005 : 02 2A                                           : .*
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Exiting Socket#3578669::Receive()   -> Int32#2
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = dbec100:7aa8d68, targetName = nfe.sertaozinho.sp.gov.br, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0461591Z
 System.Net Information: 0 : [7532] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, retornou o código=CertUnknown).
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0617859Z
 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7532] Socket#3578669::Dispose()
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0617859Z
 System.Net Error: 0 : [7532] Exceção em HttpWebRequest#13040701:: - A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS..
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0617859Z
 System.Net Error: 0 : [7532] Exceção em HttpWebRequest#13040701::GetResponse - A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS..
     ProcessId=12476
     DateTime=2018-04-10T20:14:19.0617859Z
```

Comment: o erro fala que á uma falha ao obter o sertificado ssl pela porta :8443 tem  certeza que essa é a porta correta ? pois geralmente ssl usa a porta 443

Comment: testei aqui está ok  na porta 8443

Comment: Oi Marcos, eu fiz este teste e ele responde normalmente. Mas após o erro sobre o proxy, ele segue realizando a comunicação com o serviço. Até chegar no ponto de obter o certificado, aonde ocorre outra mensagem indicando que não foi possível encontrar o certificado no repositório. Acredito que ele não encontra o certificado instalado na máquina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Consegui resolver o problema.

Solução: quando instalei o certificado digital do cliente no repositório do Windows, não marquei a caixa **Marcar esta chave como exportável. Isso possibilitará o backup ou o transporte das chaves posteriormente**. À partir do momento que ativei este recurso, o webservice conseguiu validar o canal de comunicação e possibilitou a transmissão da NFS-e.

Obrigado!

Rodrigo Duarte | ONCLICK Sistemas